# Best way to store large amounts of high resolution images for my React portfolio?

Tags: reactjs, storage, gallery, large-data, portfolio

I am developing a personal portfolio for myself using React and Gatsby, and I'm looking for a way to implement a gallery there with all my photography in it.

I need a way to efficiently store and retrieve large amounts of high-res images to use in the gallery. I was thinking about using an AWS S3 bucket (because they have a free tier) and write a simple API for retrieving these images in Node, but I want to know if there is a simpler/better option out there.

Comment: Personally I like using [Cloudinary](https://cloudinary.com/) as they have npm package and allow you to manipulate/transform images if needed.

Answer (score 0):

An S3 bucket is a good idea.  If you use a CDN like cloudflare and add the correct cache headers you can limit the data in/data out.

Gatscby has a plug-in to do you can use so you wont need to write custom-code:
https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/deploying-to-s3-cloudfront/